# If postman 401, authorize and retry

Tags: postman

For testing, we use postman pretty extensively to hit our APIs.  Right now we call one route to authorize, which stores the necessary stuff in environment variables, then hit the request we're actually interested in.  I'd like to utilize the test tab to automatically call our authorize route if the request gets a 401, then automatically try the request again.

It looks like I can call pm.setNextRequest("Name"), but that only works in the context of the Collection Runner to set the next request.  I want this to happen automatically when just running a single request.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

I'm specifically looking for answers that have nothing to do with the collection runner as that is nowhere near my use case.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use the Postman script in the Pre-request-Script section of your request to check if the response received is 401 and re-try. If you get the expected response the actual request will be called.

Comment: How can I got the response of the request in the pre-request?

Answer (score 1):

@claudekennilol,

You can use the following snippet in the Pre-Request Script. Please note that I gave you an idea of how you can use the pre-request script to call an endpoint, you can change the looping as per your needs.

```
const echoPostRequest = {
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',

  method: 'POST',
  header: 'Content-Type:application/json',
  body: {
    mode: 'application/json',
    raw: JSON.stringify(
    {
"userId": 1,
"title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
"body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
})
  }
};

var checker = true;
var iterator = 0;

do {

    pm.sendRequest(echoPostRequest, function (err, res) {

        if(res.code === 200){
            if (err === null) {
                var responseJson = res.json();
                // Do something here if condition passes

            }
        }else{
            // Do something if condition fails
        }

    });
iterator++;
}
while (iterator<10);
```